# Compute the area of differents buildings for differents regions in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, area, equal-area

I'm really new to GeoPandas so this question may have already been answered (I hope not).

I have a GeoPandas dataset with points that represent the coordinates of buildings and I would like to calculate their areas. I would like to do:

```
df=df['geometry'].area
```

However, they are located in very different places in the world and whatever the projection, I get area results that are for some buildings very high.
Do you know how to get consistent areas for the buildings?
I have tried different projections (LEA, Eckert...) but none of them can eliminate outliers.

The area should be the area of some residential area but the area is far too great...
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use groupby each row, reproject it using [.estimate_utm_crs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.estimate_utm_crs.html), and measure the area:

```
import geopandas as gpd

file = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/worldwide_squares.gpkg"
df = gpd.read_file(file)

df["tempid"] = range(df.shape[0]) #Create a unique id for each row

areas = {} #A dict to hold each polygons area

for i, subframe in df.groupby("tempid"): #For each row
    area = subframe.to_crs(subframe.estimate_utm_crs()).geometry.area #Reproject to an utm crs and calculate area
    areas[i] = area #Store it in the dict
    
df["area"] = areas #Create a column
```